# offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, offset

I am trying to clean up the way my anchors work. I have a header that is fixed to the top of the page, so when you link to an anchor elsewhere in the page, the page jumps so the anchor is at the top of the page, leaving the content behind the fixed header (I hope that makes sense).  I need a way to offset the anchor by the 25px from the height of the header. I would prefer HTML or CSS, but Javascript would be acceptable as well.

Comment: The wrapper div shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431639/general-offset-for-all-anchors-in-html is fine I think, not too aggressive.

Comment: There is a nice article on this subject: http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors

Comment: @0fnt, This is actually a duplicate of that post. Why is it not closed?

Comment: @Pacerier I think that requires moderator action. I've flagged though

Comment: Re: deleting this post, from SO: This question cannot be deleted because other questions are linked as duplicates of this one.

Comment: The question which marks this one as duplicate does not accept javascript solutions. This question has script solutions. It should be reopened.

Comment: This solution is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28824157/1066234 

Comment: i'm seeking a solution which 
* works for anchors coming in from same page or other page, 
* and which adjusts page-down key-press so that content doesn't get clipped by header, 
* and which allows sib-div footer to scroll up with content-div. Haven't found a solution yet! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070758/css-to-make-vertical-scrolling-region-under-fixed-header

Comment: @J.Bruni There is a much newer CSS-tricks.com article about `scroll-padding-top` here: https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/

Comment: I wish these posts could be updated. I use 
`:target { scroll-margin-top: 24px; }`

Comment: Add the code in your css file will fix the problem, replace your header height and gap

``html {
  --headerHeight:79px;
  --gap:40px;
  scroll-padding-top: calc(var(--headerHeight) + var(--gap));
}``

Comment: `.anchor-margin { margin-top: -110px; padding-top: 110px; }`

Comment: scroll-margin-top: 100px; is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1487):

You could just use CSS without any javascript.

Give your anchor a class:

```html
<a class="anchor" id="top"></a>
```

You can then position the anchor an offset higher or lower than where it actually appears on the page, by making it a block element and relatively positioning it. -250px will position the anchor up 250px

```css
a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer, because it doesn't depend on a parent element whose position is set to relative. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: I would advise others to use this instead of the span tag. If you're going to add markup, might as well just make it a traditional anchor tag.

Comment: Love your solution!
It seems not to work with IE7. Anyway, I plan to ignore IE7 users from now on...

Comment: If you want this to work for visible elements, you can also use a pseudo-element, a la `.thing-with-anchor:before { content: ''; display: block; position: relative; width: 0; height: 5em; margin-top: -5em }`  The display block and position relative are essential.

Comment: We are not suppose to be using a tags w/o an href attribute anymore. Instead we are suppose to use id tags within heading / section / etc for anchored text. What is the solution then?

Comment: @harpo: Nice idea, but doesn't work. Tried in Chrome 40.

Comment: @harpo I had a question about your solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101754/affixed-header-overlap-solution-causing-other-overlap-issues). Can you take a look?

Comment: Is there a nice way to handle multiple fixed header sizes e.g. responsive ones changing its height?

Comment: this didn't work for me, best one is [Alexander Savin solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11842865/1422486)

Comment: This doesn't work if we want to use :target.

Comment: For current Chrome (as of 2016) with fragment links coming in from other pages, there seems to be no CSS solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086107/html-positionfixed-page-header-and-in-page-anchors/35452468#35452468

Comment: Instead of having an explicit selector you can also use the following: `a[id]:not([href])`

Comment: This work so very well... even on mobile.. Implemented this with smooth scrolling and I was laughing away... Thanks a ton for sharing!

Comment: @harpo You should add yours as an answer...or this should be edited into the answer so people know the visible way also

Comment: I really like THIS answer better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28824157/714733 (in the dupe question)

Comment: For some reason JS rots the brain and 50 lines of JS (that is debatably a hack) to avoid a few lines of hack is not good programming. Smooth scrolling [et al] are not always wanted (performance, waste of time on critical UI).  JS is not always the answer.

Comment: To keep it dynamic you can use something like `top: calc(-<?php echo $fixed_header_height; ?> - 20px);` to have some nice space between menu and anchor.

Comment: Bad solution for me because break the margin collapsing.

Comment: it works well but the previous element before the anchor needs to have no margin bottom or the scroll position is affected

Comment: This is a really good approach for `no-script` users.

Comment: This answer should be accepted: in my case it worked perfectly, I only had to update the top property with javascript depending on the height of the fixed menu.

Comment: I am using Avada theme by Theme Fusion (a page builder) on WordPress. The website has a fixed header and the "parent" option worked, but this is more elegant, and less code to maintain. Still works in 2019!

Comment: If you want to quickly test it (checked in 2019), here is one-liner `<div class="anchor" id="gotowhatwedo" style="display: block; position: relative; top: -75px; visibility: hidden;"></div>` so you can go here using `<a href="#gotowhatwedo">click here</a>` . That's it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be this instead? `a[name] {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -3em;
    visibility: hidden;
}`

Comment: This just worked for me with Bootstrap 4: *<div id="my-location-to-navigate-to" class="d-block position-relative d-none" style="top: -250px;"></div>*

Comment: @harpo, This blocks texts and links that are covered up by the invisible element, making them unselectable and unclickable.

Comment: The updated answer for this (as of 2021) is to use `scroll-padding` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-padding/

Comment: It just lets my anchor dissapear

Comment: Should consider editing to use <span> instead of <a>. For accessibility <a> wants an href attribute. It works the same for me when I switched out.

Comment: Update 2022: This does not work at all. I can also add -500px, it still jumps too far down.

Comment: @qxotk : this work fine. But why `d-block` and `d-none` together?

Comment: @basZero can't recall at present, might be that I was navigating to a label only used for assistive tech, like screen readers.

Answer (score 456):

I found this solution:

```html
<a name="myanchor">
    <h1 style="padding-top: 40px; margin-top: -40px;">My anchor</h1>
</a>
```

This doesn't create any gap in the content and anchor links works really nice.

Comment: Worked great. I created a special CSS anchor class and just attached it to my anchors: <a class="anchor" name="foo"></a>. Thanks.

Comment: there is still jankiness with the indicator in the nav. so if you scroll down the page, the active nav item doesn't switch until you scroll past the anchor target.

Comment: Element just above <h1> will not be clickable, because of the hidden padding/margin. I ended up using Ian Clack's jQuery solution, which works great.

Comment: How would you make it work with anchors that use element IDs, i.e. <h1 id="smth">Text</h1>...<a href="#smth">Link</a>?

Comment: I think I figured this out: h2[id], h3[id], h4[id], a[name] { padding-top: XXpx; padding-bottom: XXpx; } It applies to all h2, h3, h4 tags with IDs, as well as named anchors.

Comment: I don't think having a header tag inside of a link is standards compliant, but it works! +1

Comment: @Mathijs : I had the same problem. I simply replaced it with `<a name="myanchor" style="padding-top: 40px; margin-top: -40px;"></a>My anchor` and it works great, without jQuery (invisible and 0px anchor target)

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Comment: @Nate it's compliant. Try the W3C HTML Validator or see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7023512/1709587.

Comment: Down vote as anchors with the name attribute are no longer supported from HTML 5, so should be linking to id of object

Comment: To prevent the issue with elements directly above not being clickable, you can set a negative z-index on the h* element.

`h3[id] {
    z-index: -1;
}`

Comment: @Matt have you tried to apply negative z-index to anchor element?

Comment: Problem not solved. Anchor is still under the fixed header.

Answer (score 252):

FWIW this worked for me:

```
[id]::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height:      75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Comment: I don't fully understand why this works, but +1 from me. None of the others were as easy to implement or worked as well as this. :-)

Comment: I wrapped this in a media query so it is only applied to medium and large screens where I have a fixed nav.

Comment: This may work, but it will overlap the content before the headline.

Comment: You could add `position: relative` and `z-index: -1` to prevent it overlapping previous content. At least that worked for me

Comment: Do not work if you have background image for your element for exeample... (because the size of the element change with this hack)

Comment: And it preserves collapse of margins, absolutely beautiful!

Comment: Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: This is my favorite solution of all the answers here, but it's not a good approach when the links element is itself a link—the height value creates a big strike pad that extends past the area a user would expect to be linked. To keep the strike pad smaller, I did this: `content: '\00a0'; width: '1px'; margin-left: '-1px';padding-top: 75px;` -- this creates a valid element that pushes down the scroll bar without leaving any unexpected clickable areas.

Comment: This is great! However, it doesn't work if the `[id]` element is a child of `display: flex` container: the height created by the `::before` element doesn't affect the height of the `[id]` element because flex ‍♀️

Comment: Unfortunately increases the element size which causes its `border` and `outline` to be drawn around the `before` element.

Comment: Definitely the easiest & best solution in 2020!
As @kylesimmonds pointed out, an additional tweak is needed to prevent the pseudo-element from overlapping any (clickable) content above: `[id]::before { position: relative; z-index: -1; }`. If the host element has relative/absolute/fixed position, those styles will need to be added there:  `[id] { position: relative; z-index: -1; }`.

Comment: I have a ton of elements with IDs that aren't anchors. This wreaks havoc with them.

Comment: @jamesfacts, no you can just do it like this then `<h3><span id="one"></span><a href="#two">one</a></h3>`

Comment: The solution looks good, but it destroys the whole layout of our website if I add the css.

Comment: @BradyHolt this may probably be irrelevant now for you, but anyways: what it says is this, if you encounter an element with an id apply this in between this element and element before it. "this" would be position the pseudo element x pixel lower.

Comment: I have no idea how it works, but it works! The invisible block corrected the landing of the scroll. Thumbs up!

Comment: addition `position: absolute` also works to keep the before element from reflowing the rest of your page.

Comment: wish I could party with you all but its not working for me :( (using with bootstrap 4.x.x)

Comment: This solution is magic!

Answer (score 226):

I was looking for a solution to this as well. In my case, it was pretty easy.

I have a list menu with all the links:

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
<li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
</ul>
```

And below that the headings where it should go to.

```html
<h3>one</h3>
<p>text here</p>

<h3>two</h3>
<p>text here</p>

<h3>three</h3>
<p>text here</p>

<h3>four</h3>
<p>text here</p>
```

Now because I have a fixed menu at the top of my page I can't just make it go to my  tag because that would be behind the menu.

Instead, I put a span tag inside my  tag with the proper id.

```html
<h3><span id="one"></span>one</h3>
```

Now use 2 lines of CSS to position them properly.

```css
h3{ position:relative; }
h3 span{ position:absolute; top:-200px;}
```

Change the top value to match the height of your fixed header (or more).
Now I assume this would work with other elements as well.

Comment: `span` could be replaced with an `a`

Comment: This works really nice and avoids some of the problems I hit with other techniques, such as when using an h2 tag that sets a padding-top.

Comment: I use this, as well as a JS event listening for click events on the anchors to smooth scroll if JS is available.

Comment: In Wordpress, empty <a></a> get stripped out. This solution, the editor does not strip out the empty spans. This is great!

Comment: I added a class to the `<span>` element so the children span do not inherit the same styling.

Comment: This is a superb solution, in my situation (I have React/Next) I gave the h5 tag the class of anchor and the inner span my id name (so Link was happy). Then just set the anchor class to position relative and the inner span to position absolute and top -3rem. Using Sass made it easier too, so thanks for this direction.

Answer (score 189):

As this is a concern of presentation, a pure CSS solution would be ideal. However, this question was posed in 2012, and although relative positioning / negative margin solutions have been suggested, these approaches seem rather hacky, create potential flow issues, and cannot respond dynamically to changes in the DOM / viewport.

With that in mind I believe that using JavaScript is *still* (February 2017) the best approach. Below is a vanilla-JS solution which will respond both to anchor clicks and resolve the page hash on load **[(See JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/eqtosjtv/)**. Modify the `.getFixedOffset()` method if dynamic calculations are required. If you're using jQuery, [here's a modified solution with better event delegation and smooth scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/rkocah23/).

```
(function(document, history, location) {
  var HISTORY_SUPPORT = !!(history && history.pushState);

  var anchorScrolls = {
    ANCHOR_REGEX: /^#[^ ]+$/,
    OFFSET_HEIGHT_PX: 50,

    /**
     * Establish events, and fix initial scroll position if a hash is provided.
     */
    init: function() {
      this.scrollToCurrent();
      window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.scrollToCurrent.bind(this));
      document.body.addEventListener('click', this.delegateAnchors.bind(this));
    },

    /**
     * Return the offset amount to deduct from the normal scroll position.
     * Modify as appropriate to allow for dynamic calculations
     */
    getFixedOffset: function() {
      return this.OFFSET_HEIGHT_PX;
    },

    /**
     * If the provided href is an anchor which resolves to an element on the
     * page, scroll to it.
     * @param  {String} href
     * @return {Boolean} - Was the href an anchor.
     */
    scrollIfAnchor: function(href, pushToHistory) {
      var match, rect, anchorOffset;

      if(!this.ANCHOR_REGEX.test(href)) {
        return false;
      }

      match = document.getElementById(href.slice(1));

      if(match) {
        rect = match.getBoundingClientRect();
        anchorOffset = window.pageYOffset + rect.top - this.getFixedOffset();
        window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, anchorOffset);

        // Add the state to history as-per normal anchor links
        if(HISTORY_SUPPORT && pushToHistory) {
          history.pushState({}, document.title, location.pathname + href);
        }
      }

      return !!match;
    },

    /**
     * Attempt to scroll to the current location's hash.
     */
    scrollToCurrent: function() {
      this.scrollIfAnchor(window.location.hash);
    },

    /**
     * If the click event's target was an anchor, fix the scroll position.
     */
    delegateAnchors: function(e) {
      var elem = e.target;

      if(
        elem.nodeName === 'A' &&
        this.scrollIfAnchor(elem.getAttribute('href'), true)
      ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener(
    'DOMContentLoaded', anchorScrolls.init.bind(anchorScrolls)
  );
})(window.document, window.history, window.location);
```

Comment: works great, though for jquery 1.7+, use 
$("a").on("click",... 
instead of 
$("a").live("click",...

Comment: Nice comment, I'll update :) - BTW it should also be `$("body").on("click", "a"...` as it may need to work for anchors which are added into the document by scripts (hence why I was using `.live`)

Comment: +1: in pure CSS soln, elements above aren't clickable (eg, when a side navbar moves on top for small screens)

Comment: Also, though, it's worth noting that this will mess with other href/id pairs, as in collapse, carousel, etc... is there an easy way around this?

Comment: @tom10 I suppose you would just have to make the selector more specific, either by blacklisting anchors using `a:not(.not-anchor)` (or something less confusingly named) and then make sure that your collapse/carousel libraries add those classes to their anchors. If you're using jQuery UI or Bootstrap I imagine they add some other classes which you could reference.

Comment: @IanClark: Thanks for the tips.  (In retrospect, I should have made that an independent SO question.)

Comment: @tom10 I've added a few conditions to the test for `#` in the `href` in order to avoid breaking collapse and carousel: `if(href.indexOf("#") == 0 && (!$(this).data() || this.self == window))`

Comment: @raddevon But any element could happen to have some jQuery data attached to it, I think that could prove quite a frustrating gotcha in the future.

Comment: That's true. I can't think of a more accurate way to special case all of Bootstrap's JS components without doing each one individually. This solution also doesn't address JS components configured outside data attributes.

Comment: Looks like bootstrap elements such as Carousel and Tabs have a `data-toggle` attribute, you could check for that?

Comment: @raddevon.  That if statement is blowing me away.  I get the lead character == '#' portion, but don't get the rest of the AND stuff. In current form, my internal anchor links all fail your test, and I can't figure out why.  The 'this' thing is confusing.. isn't 'this' = to the function scroll_if_anchor().  What your intent? thnx.

Comment: @zipzit - I guess he added that before I changed the approach slightly. At that point the `this` would always have been the anchor element which fired the event. He's just suggesting that you add another condition to check that it's a "standard" anchor, and not something used be a JS function (like a carousel).

Comment: @zipzit It's a pretty naïve approach that worked in my case. Ian is right that it was written when `this` would have referred to the target element. I'm not running the code on anything that has a data attribute unless it's the window object.

Comment: I had a lot of difficulty getting this routine to work.  Some weird timing issues.  I ended up with  `jQuery('a').click(function(){
setTimeout(function(){scroll_if_anchor(window.location.hash)},400); })` for the last 'intercept all anchor clicks' call.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Comment: @Shog9 OK, but maybe the word "navbar" made the other question useful.

Comment: The other question still exists as a signpost - anyone finding it in search results for "navbar" will be redirected to this question.

Comment: This is incredible - thank you!  However, I have a page with dynamic content that's populating and changing the position of everything below it.  So if you get anchored to something below that dynamic content, you end up on the wrong spot.  Any way to "re-calculate" where to land after all dynamic content has populated?   Note that we're scrolling to the id="foo" anchor, not an a name="foo" kind of anchor.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Why not just call .height() on the things you're trying to calculate? You'll need to do it in the ready block when the DOM is loaded, and if you style the height to a variable in the outer scope, it'll be available to the scroll_if_anchor method

Comment: If `history` is indeed unset, as you check in `if (history && ...)`, then it will cause a ReferenceError for a variable not defined. Instead, check for a property on window -- `if (window.history && ...)`

Comment: FYI, someone can sort of hack your function by writing a jQuery selector as the href value: `<a href="#heading1 > .sub-class ul + ul li">`

Comment: @MatthiasDailey updated the solution to vanilla JS and fixed your problems above :)

Comment: Excellent thanks! I had links to other pages with anchors as well, e.g. `/page/#anchor`. This regex covers those: `/^[\/a-z0-9-]*#[^\s]+$/`

Comment: Though the solution adds entries to the history, it doesn't listen to hashchange and then no scrolling happens at all when trying to go back.

Comment: @neo good spot, added - though smooth scrolling doesn't seem to apply with the jQuery variant despite the `preventDefault()` call.

Comment: Strange problem which I don't have a chance of resolving myself; in Google Chrome v54. It doesn't work when you first load the page (or if you refresh) but it works if you change the # on the page, eg page.html#1 doesn't work first time (no error), page.html#2 works perfectly if called from the page, page.html#1 then works. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChrisPink this works for me on Chrome 54: http://output.jsbin.com/cepigagowa#target-3

Comment: Trying to make this responsive.  I use   
<script>
 // handles setting page content below responsive header on initial page load
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var contentPlacement = jQuery('#header').position().top + jQuery('#header').height();
      jQuery('.rev_slider_wrapper').css('padding-top',contentPlacement);
  });
 </script>
to adjust my header for the slider.  Am trying to set OFFSET_HEIGHT_PX to the same calculation as the above code, but no matter how I write it it isn't working.  Any help on setting this would be appreciated.

Comment: I ended up with this replacement for the getFixedOffset function to have a responsive header height: 
    getFixedOffset: function() { 
        var responsiveHeight =     jQuery('#header').position().top + jQuery('#header').height();
        return responsiveHeight;
    }

Comment: If you are clicking 2 times on the same anchor consecutively (from menu with anchor links), the second click is not working well.

Comment: Still working in 2018. Great JQuery solution, thanks. Would love to know if someone has a better way by now or not though, this was the best I could find

Comment: Changing the scroll position in the `DOMContentLoaded` event works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: I fixed the issue where clicking on the same anchor link twice by swapping the line inside `delegateAnchors` that says `var elem = e.target;` to `var elem = e.currentTarget;`. I don't think this change breaks anything...

Comment: @IanClark IE Edge doesn't support scrollTop and in fact won't scroll at all. I've had to check for edge and use `$(match).scrollIntoView()` when using edge. `/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)` will test for Edge. Maybe you could update your excellent fiddle?

Comment: @Ian Clark Very elegant & thorough solution. Worked perfectly, once I changed the 'name' attribute to 'id' attribute in the accompanying '<a name>' tag. Thanks. Upvoted...

Comment: this does not work on page load right? Only when I click an anchor on the page?

Comment: I figured out the cause of the issue where clicking a second time on the anchor does not work. The regex only works with links that begin with `#`, not links like `/some-url/#anchor`. It was always returning false in the scrollIfAnchor function, whereas the scrollToCurrent function was working.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found after quite some searching, though it does have one issue: if you go to an anchor it works fine, but if you then go to the browsers URL bar and hit enter, you'll end up on the wrong spot, since the hashchange event is not triggered.

Comment: To adapt for responsive web design, replace the this.OFFSET_HEIGHT_PX with a reference to the header element's offsetHeight (or similar). Even with a fixed header, this would be better since the height value is only specified once (in the CSS) - the JS doesn't need to be updated at all if the layout is changed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Didn't validate it too much, but I fixed the bug when you click an anchor link twice and added a dynamic offset for bootstrap navbars: https://pastebin.com/gdHdAhSb

Comment: href reference from top to bottom working, but bottom to top not working.

Comment: @MikeW that seems really odd... the bottom of the file uses a closure to assign `location` to `window.location`. In any event it _should_ be a singleton. Are you able to confirm?

Comment: Of course you are right - my bad. I just realised for my use case I had removed it from the closure - I'll delete my comment. Nice code btw.

Comment: Works great for the desktop version of my site, but leaves wayyyyy too much space above my target anchors in the mobile version of the site. It stops scrolling much too early before reaching the target anchors. I'm not sure why either; I've used updated code to have the "responsiveHeight" instead of the fixed height too. But the height of the header between desktop & mobile sites is only a few pixel difference so that's not the problem, I'd think. I'm not sure where the issue lies.

Answer (score 95):

Pure css solution inspired by Alexander Savin:

```
a[name] {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  display: inline-block; /* required for webkit browsers */
}
```

Optionally you may want to add the following if the target is still off the screen:

```
  vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: I have just tried on Chrome and the display inline-block was not required.

Comment: @Asrail For me it didn't work without it

Comment: For me, "display: inline-block;" completely broke functionality in Chrome (all links became unclickable).

Comment: a[name] selector should not  be affected to links

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Comment: If there is a link just above the anchor it cannot be clicked. Add the following two rules:
position: relative;
z-index: -1;

Comment: This solution works if you are coming from an external link and using the anchor to jump to

Comment: @Asrail It won't work without it for me too. (Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: 2022: This works for all major browsers without the `inline-block` statement. 

You might need `block` … did not test.

Answer (score 88):

My solution combines the target and before selectors for our CMS. Other techniques don't account for text in the anchor. Adjust the height and the negative margin to the offset you need...

```css
:target::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height:      180px;
    margin-top: -180px;
}
```

Comment: These two CSS solutions didn't work for me on the first sight, but finally I found out it **might not be compatible with other CSS properties**. Added a wrapper and that fixed the problem. Combination of :target:before with display:block works best for me.

Comment: [Solved] This solution works and i used this solution with `display: block;`. Without a special class, empty tag or javascript.

Comment: If you decide to use this method, it is probably a good idea to add `pointer-events: none;` as well. Because otherwise links intersecting with the invisible overlay (above the anchor) will not be clickable.

Comment: This solution messes up collapsed margins by disconnecting them. Edit: I just put the id on the `<h1>` and not the `<section>` and it works fine

Comment: Great otherwise but if the parent of the target element has `grid-area: named-area` the required offset cannot escape the grid area and the resulting actual offset may be too short. I haven't found a good workaround that special case so this should be considered as the correct answer in general.

Comment: If supporting just modern browsers is okay, I'd recommend just `:target { scroll-margin-top: 180px; }` (or any other measurement or `calc()` you wish).

Answer (score 49):

This takes many elements from previous answers and combines into a tiny (194 bytes minified) anonymous jQuery function.  Adjust *fixedElementHeight* for the height of your menu or blocking element.

```
    (function($, window) {
        var adjustAnchor = function() {

            var $anchor = $(':target'),
                    fixedElementHeight = 100;

            if ($anchor.length > 0) {

                $('html, body')
                    .stop()
                    .animate({
                        scrollTop: $anchor.offset().top - fixedElementHeight
                    }, 200);

            }

        };

        $(window).on('hashchange load', function() {
            adjustAnchor();
        });

    })(jQuery, window);
```

If you don't like the animation, replace

```
$('html, body')
     .stop()
     .animate({
         scrollTop: $anchor.offset().top - fixedElementHeight
     }, 200);
```

with:

```
window.scrollTo(0, $anchor.offset().top - fixedElementHeight);
```

Uglified version:

```
 !function(o,n){var t=function(){var n=o(":target"),t=100;n.length>0&&o("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:n.offset().top-t},200)};o(n).on("hashchange load",function(){t()})}(jQuery,window);
```

Comment: This solution really helped me out, but it is somehow not working consistently in IE9-11. Sometimes it works, some other clicks it doesn't (scroll position stays at the anchor position). I am totally out of ideas what could cause the issue.

Comment: @Crono1985 Is your doc HTML 4 or 5?  In 4, IDs had a stricter list of characters so they may be failing to register as valid targets.

Next, are you using ID or name?  In HTML5, ID is a valid anchor for all tags but name can only be used on link tags.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! The only problem, it doesn't reliably work, if one follows the link with fragment/hash (I mean some-page#anchor). At least on Chromium 45.0.2454.101 and Firefox. I'm not sure it could fixed though.

Comment: @MajesticRa One tricky issue is the order of operations in the on load or scroll events.  If your page adjusts the layout after the page is loaded or scrolled (shrinking masthead for example), the calculation of the :target offset can be wrong.

Comment: That solved my issue. Maybe it worth putting this remark in the answer.

Comment: I really don't understand why it doesn't work in IE11. Is pure HTML5 and name attribute on link tags.

Comment: Is the $(':target'), IE11 returns "length": 0, therefore the animate code doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidPrieto careful to check you have a valid anchor.  It works with well formed IDs, not names.  

For instance, in both IE11 and Edge I get length=1 on this URL:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header/29853395?noredirect=1#comment-56627664

Comment: href reference from top to bottom working, but bottom to top not working.

Comment: `window.scrollTo({
     top: $anchor.offset().top - fixedElementHeight,
     behavior: 'smooth'
    });`
this works for me

Answer (score 45):

For modern browsers, just add the CSS3 :target selector to the page. This will apply to all the anchors automatically.

```
:target {
    display: block;    
    position: relative;     
    top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You could even do `:target:before` to create a hidden pseudo-element rather than hide the whole target.

Comment: The :target selector is supposed to be supported since IE9, but the offset only works with FF and Chrome and Safari on my site, not with IE 11.

Comment: I guess you could argue that IE is not a modern browser. Either way, by using a CSS class instead of the :target selector it works fine in IE as well.

Comment: When you do things the HTML5 way (and I think 4 too) where you target an id attribute within a node such as section or header, this way caused the element to display overlapping elements above it.

Comment: Hiding `:target` seems like a bad idea in most contexts. You're granting anybody who sends someone a link to your page the power to pick any element with an ID and delete it from the page that the viewer will see. On the tame side, tech-savvy pranksters may well notice this and decide to have some fun with it, much as they once had fun with the ability to make links to some news sites show up with silly titles on Facebook by manipulating their URLs. More severely, it may be a security hole if your page has something like a "don't share this secret information with anyone" message with an ID.

Comment: adding this code to the style sheet does nothing for me using Chrome 60.0.3112.78 in the website I'm currently working on - though that may well be due to interaction effects... Could you post a pen?

Comment: I couldn't use this cause it'd hide the place I was going, but I just placed a ```<b id="anchor"></b>``` where I was going and now everything is fine (I know it's not that orthodox but whatever).

Answer (score 42):

### You can do it without js and without altering html. It´s css-only.

```
a[id]::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: -30px 0 0;
}
```

That will append a pseudo-element before every a-tag with an id. Adjust values to match the height of your header.

Comment: Interesting idea, but note that this screws up the display if you happen to have visible links with `id`'s.

Comment: If you have ever wonder why it doesn't work for you, check out if parent element has not *border* or *padding*.

Comment: i modified this to select `:target[id]:before` since the id's that i anchor-link to are sometimes h1-h6.

Comment: a[id]:before can be changed to something else like div[name]:before

Comment: height and negative margin should match right?

Comment: FYI `:target[id]:before` is the same as `:target:before` since `:target` selects elements with an ID matching the page fragment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Comment: Awesome and simple generic solution for ID anchor. Thank you for that. :)

Answer (score 34):

I had been facing a similar issue, unfortunately after implementing all the solutions above, I came to the following conclusion.

1. My inner elements had a fragile CSS structure and implementing a position relative / absolute play, was completely breaking the page design.
2. CSS is not my strong suit.

I wrote this simple scrolling js, that accounts for the offset caused due to the header and relocated the div about 125 pixels below. Please use it as you see fit.

The HTML

```
<div id="#anchor"></div> <!-- #anchor here is the anchor tag which is on your URL -->
```

The JavaScript

```
 $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 125 //offsets for fixed header
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  //Executed on page load with URL containing an anchor tag.
  if($(location.href.split("#")[1])) {
      var target = $('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 125 //offset height of header here too.
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

See a [live implementation here](http://scholowiz.herokuapp.com/about#change).

Comment: ok i got the anchor to put the anchor name into the url, but i cant seem to get the second part to work.  When i open my page with an anchor in the url, it moves to where the anchor is but it won't offset it.  Do i need something in addition to jquery to make that work?

Comment: @Robbiegod to offset just tweak the pixel count I have mentioned, `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 125` the 125 here is something that worked for me. Refine it as per your needs. It would be great if you could post an example with your problem for more clarifications.

Comment: @Shouvik I did change 125 to 165 to match my site already, but it still doesnt offset.  I have the js code in a file called site.js at that file loads in the footer, could that be the problem?  Does this need to load in the head section?  I also copied your code straight into my site.js file.  The total change i made was changing the $ to jQuery.

Comment: hmmm, it shouldn't be an issue. The idea is that we want to call this function after the window is loaded as opposed to the page being ready. This is done to take the images loaded into perspective to scroll the page. You should probably check your jquery reference, i.e if the jquery file is loaded. Use the `$` instead of `JQuery`. If you are getting an error it's probably because the jquery is not getting loaded.

Comment: jQuery is loading for sure (lightboxes, flexslider etc all work).  I load jQuery in the footer too.  Then i load my site.js file. using jquery 1.11 and jquery ui as well. i changed all of the jQuery back to $ (though i don't think this is an issue either way because $ is just an alias for jQuery) - it seemed to not make any difference. I don't see any errors, but also when i open a new browser and paste the url with the anchor it doesnt offset the page.  I'll keep trying different stuff

Comment: @Shouvik i did some digging.  Found out that <code>var target = jQuery('#'+location.href.split("#")[1]);</code> returns an array, but when i output the console.log(target.length); it returns a zero.  For this to work, what value does var target need to be?

Comment: @Robbiegod your location.href is the URL which should have the anchor tag. We split it by # to get the tag id. The `('#'+location.href.split("#")[1])` basically get's the element, and should return 1. Do you have the anchor tag as a div id in your page? If not then this will not work. See my live implementation link and debug the code to learn more. I will not be of much help unless you can give me a link to your site. HTH :)

Comment: This will not serve you well if your website uses dynamic sizing units such as `em` or `rem`s for the header size since the offsets will differ maybe even per user. Also if you'd change the header to be less high at a smaller viewport this would require manual tweaking or taking into account all sizes you want to use. Not to mention that there will be a moment where the header will jump due to JS loading ever so slightly later. All that and the fact that it uses JS to perform a CSS task. Kudos for solving it but I would refrain from using it for those reasons.

Answer (score 14):

For the same issue, I used an easy solution : put a padding-top of 40px on each anchor.

Comment: Thanks, this was basically what I ended up doing, but I was wondering whether there's a solution for situations where adding extra padding might be awkward.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Answer (score 13):

As @moeffju suggests, this can be [achieved with CSS](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/). The issue I ran into (which I'm surprised I haven't seen discussed) is the trick of overlapping previous elements with padding or a transparent border prevents hover and click actions at the bottom of those sections because the following one comes higher in the z-order.

The best fix I found was to place section content in a `div` that is at `z-index: 1`:

```
// Apply to elements that serve as anchors
.offset-anchor {
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  margin: -75px 0 0;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

// Because offset-anchor causes sections to overlap the bottom of previous ones,
// we need to put content higher so links aren't blocked by the transparent border.
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Solutions with changing position property are not always possible (it can destroy layout) therefore I suggest this:

HTML:

```
<a id="top">Anchor</a>
```

CSS:

```
#top {
    margin-top: -250px;
    padding-top: 250px;
}
```

Use this:

```
<a id="top">&nbsp;</a>
```

to minimize overlapping, and set font-size to 1px. Empty anchor will not work in some browsers.

Answer (score 11):

Borrowing some of the code from an answer given [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804941/how-to-add-smooth-scrolling-to-bootstraps-scroll-spy-function) (no author is specified), you can include a nice smooth-scroll effect to the anchor, while making it stop at -60px above the anchor, fitting nicely underneath the fixed bootstrap navigation bar (requires jQuery):

```
$(".dropdown-menu a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault();

   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 60
     }, 300, function(){
     });
});
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Comment: A full solution should also include the scenario in which a user loads a new page with the anchor already in the address bar. I tried to adapt this code to fire upon the $(document).ready event but it is still scrolling to the wrong place in the document. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks, that is the solution for twitter bootstrap users

Comment: @AdamFriedman did you even found a solution to that specifik scenario. I use a smoothanchor library which I can append an offset but that also does not work on pageloads with urls. url#target

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having a fixed-position navbar which is underlapped by the rest of the content of the page (with the whole page body being scrollable), consider instead having a non-scrollable body with a static navbar and then having the page content in an absolutely-positioned scrollable div below.

That is, have HTML like this...

```
<div class="static-navbar">NAVBAR</div>
<div class="scrollable-content">
  <p>Bla bla bla</p>
  <p>Yadda yadda yadda</p>
  <p>Mary had a little lamb</p>
  <h2 id="stuff-i-want-to-link-to">Stuff</h2>
  <p>More nonsense</p>
</div>
```

... and CSS like this:

```
.static-navbar {
  height: 100px;
}
.scrollable-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

There is one significant downside to this approach, however, which is that while an element from the page header is focused, the user will not be able to scroll the page using the keyboard (e.g. via the up and down arrows or the Page Up and Page Down keys).

[Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/69dx1dec/)

Comment: Non-hacky, but: (1) entirely useless outside this example, (2) cumbersome to adopt and maintain, (3) anti-semantic and-or css-abusive, (4) unintuitive. I'll take the _clean_  `a:before {...}` solution over this any day!

Comment: Best answer for me. I am using it now. All the answers here are hacky. Adding a "before" pseudo element to everything is not acceptable for me and can potentially interfere with many other CSS elements already using the "before" pseudo element. This is the right and clean way to proceed.

Comment: This is ABSOLUTELY the best solution. It requires no hacks or pseudo-classes. I also find it 100% semantic. Essentially there is a part of the page that you want to have scroll, and you set that explicitly. Also, it completely solves the problem of  how to make headings disappear behind navs with no background.

Answer (score 4):

The above methods don't work very well if your anchor is a table element or within a table (row or cell).

I had to use javascript and bind to the window `hashchange` event to work around this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3afdN/)):

```
function moveUnderNav() {
    var $el, h = window.location.hash;
    if (h) {
        $el = $(h);
        if ($el.length && $el.closest('table').length) {
            $('body').scrollTop( $el.closest('table, tr').position().top - 26 );
        }
    }
}

$(window)
    .load(function () {
        moveUnderNav();
    })
    .on('hashchange', function () {
        moveUnderNav();
    });
```

* Note: The [hashchange](http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange) event is not available in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this without an ID using the `a[name]:not([href])` css selector. This simply looks for links with a name and no href e.g. `<a name="anc1"></a>`

An example rule might be:

```
a[name]:not([href]){
    display: block;    
    position: relative;     
    top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Note that in HTML5, the `a` element has no `name` attribute, so this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

This was inspired by the answer by Shouvik - same concept as his, only the size of the fixed header isn't hard coded. As long as your fixed header is in the first header node, this should "just work"

```
/*jslint browser: true, plusplus: true, regexp: true */

function anchorScroll(fragment) {
    "use strict";
    var amount, ttarget;
    amount = $('header').height();
    ttarget = $('#' + fragment);
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: ttarget.offset().top - amount }, 250);
    return false;
}

function outsideToHash() {
    "use strict";
    var fragment;
    if (window.location.hash) {
        fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        anchorScroll(fragment);
    }
}

function insideToHash(nnode) {
    "use strict";
    var fragment;
    fragment = $(nnode).attr('href').substring(1);
    anchorScroll(fragment);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("a[href^='#']").bind('click',  function () {insideToHash(this); });
    outsideToHash();
});
```

Comment: Oh - also this solution assumes the id attribute is used for the anchor, not the deprecated name attribute.

Comment: I like this solution, very modular and beautifully done. Oh I miss the days of JQuery and DOM manipulations :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing this problem in a TYPO3 website, where all "Content Elements" are wrapped with something like:

```
<div id="c1234" class="contentElement">...</div>
```

and i changed the rendering so it renders like this:

```
<div id="c1234" class="anchor"></div>
<div class="contentElement">...</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.anchor{
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
```

The fixed topbar being 40px high, now the anchors work again and start 10px under the topbar.

Only drawback of this technique is you can no longer use `:target`.

Comment: Actually you can use :target like so: `.anchor:target+div`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ziav's answer (with thanks to Alexander Savin), I need to be using the old-school `<a name="...">...</a>` as we're using `<div id="...">...</div>` for another purpose in our code. I had some display issues using `display: inline-block` -- the first line of every `<p>` element was turning out to be slightly right-indented (on both Webkit and Firefox browsers). I ended up trying other `display` values and `display: table-caption` works perfectly for me.

```
.anchor {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  display: table-caption;
}
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Answer (score 0):

I added 40px-height `.vspace` element holding the anchor before each of my `h1` elements.

```
<div class="vspace" id="gherkin"></div>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Gherkin</h1>
</div>
```

In the CSS:

```
.vspace { height: 40px;}
```

It's working great and the space is not chocking.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Answer (score 0):

how about hidden span tags with linkable IDs that provide the height of the navbar:

```
#head1 {
  padding-top: 60px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}


<span class="head1">somecontent</span>
<h5 id="headline1">This Headline is not obscured</h5>
```

heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6f2f/7

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an anchor with follow attr:

```
(text-indent:-99999px;)
visibility: hidden;
position:absolute;
top:-80px;
```

and give the parent container a position relative.

Works perfect for me.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Answer (score 0):

A further twist to the excellent answer from @Jan is to incorporate this into the #uberbar fixed header, which uses jQuery (or MooTools). (http://davidwalsh.name/persistent-header-opacity)

I've tweaked the code so the the top of the content is always below not under the fixed header and also added the anchors from @Jan again making sure that the anchors are always positioned below the fixed header.

The CSS:

```
#uberbar { 
    border-bottom:1px solid #0000cc; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index:2000; 
    width:100%;
}

a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The jQuery (including tweaks to both the #uberbar and the anchor approaches:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        //settings
        var fadeSpeed = 200, fadeTo = 0.85, topDistance = 30;
        var topbarME = function() { $('#uberbar').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,1); }, topbarML = function() { $('#uberbar').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,fadeTo); };
        var inside = false;
        //do
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            position = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(position > topDistance && !inside) {
                //add events
                topbarML();
                $('#uberbar').bind('mouseenter',topbarME);
                $('#uberbar').bind('mouseleave',topbarML);
                inside = true;
            }
            else if (position < topDistance){
                topbarME();
                $('#uberbar').unbind('mouseenter',topbarME);
                $('#uberbar').unbind('mouseleave',topbarML);
                inside = false;
            }
        });
        $('#content').css({'margin-top': $('#uberbar').outerHeight(true)});
        $('a.anchor').css({'top': - $('#uberbar').outerHeight(true)});
    })();
});
</script>
```

And finally the HTML:

```
<div id="uberbar">
    <!--CONTENT OF FIXED HEADER-->
</div>
....
<div id="content">
    <!--MAIN CONTENT-->
    ....
    <a class="anchor" id="anchor1"></a>
    ....
    <a class="anchor" id="anchor2"></a>
    ....
</div>
```

Maybe this is useful to somebody who likes the #uberbar fading dixed header!

Answer (score -1):

@AlexanderSavin's solution works great in `WebKit` browsers for me.

I additionally had to use [:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3atarget) pseudo-class which applies style to the selected anchor to adjust padding in `FF`, `Opera` & `IE9`:

```
a:target {
  padding-top: 40px
}
```

*Note that this style is not for `Chrome` / `Safari` so you'll probably have to use css-hacks, conditional comments etc.*

Also I'd like to notice that Alexander's solution works due to the fact that targeted element is `inline`. If you don't want link you could simply change `display` property:

```
<div id="myanchor" style="display: inline">
   <h1 style="padding-top: 40px; margin-top: -40px;">My anchor</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: my nav items link to h2 elements, which are all display: block. i am using chrome, and i did not need to set the h2's to inline or inline-block.

Comment: @the0ther I was referring to wrapper element not headers. Also experiencing difficulties to imagine your markup based on your words.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution that we use on our site. Adjust the `headerHeight` variable to whatever your header height is. Add the `js-scroll` class to the anchor that should scroll on click.

```
// SCROLL ON CLICK
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
$('.js-scroll').click(function(){
    var headerHeight = 60;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - headerHeight;
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this same issue and ended up handling the click events manually, like:

```
$('#mynav a').click(() ->
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40
  }, 200
  return false
)
```

Scroll animation optional, of course.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047703/fixed-position-navbar-obscures-anchors

Comment: This javascript isn't even valid, I understand the message you're trying to convey. But it should AT LEAST have valid braces and syntax to be a legitimate answer.