# JavaScript issue with scrollTo() in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scrollto

I try to create a web page with a fixed navigation bar at the top that covers the content underneath. When loading the page with an anchor in the url the normal behaviour is that the page scrolls the anchor to the top of the window. But then that content is hidden under the navigation bar. So I try to solve this problem with JavaScript scrollTo(). My solution works fine with Firefox and Opera but not in Chrome. Please try the example. Any ideas how to fix this issue in Chrome? Thank you.

test.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <style type='text/css'>
      #navi { position:fixed; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100px; background-color:yellow; }
      #spacer { background-color:cyan; height:100px; }
      #spacer2 { height:1000px; }
      .style1 { background-color:green; height:200px; }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      /* <![CDATA[ */
      function scrollAnchor() {  // doesn't work in Chrome
        var y = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substr(1)).offsetTop - 110;
        window.scrollTo(0, y);
        //alert(y);
      }
      /* ]]> */
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id='top' onload='scrollAnchor();'>
    <div id='navi'>
      <a href='./test2.htm'>Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div id='main'>
      <div id='spacer'></div>
      <h3 id='1'>Heading 1</h3><p class='style1'></p>
      <h3 id='2'>Heading 2</h3><p class='style1'></p>
      <h3 id='3'>Heading 3</h3><p class='style1'></p>
      <h3 id='4'>Heading 4</h3><p class='style1'></p>
      <h3 id='5'>Heading 5</h3><p class='style1'></p>
      <h3 id='6'>Heading 6</h3><p class='style1'></p>
      <div id='spacer2'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

test2.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='test.htm#1'>Heading 1</a>
    <a href='test.htm#2'>Heading 2</a>
    <a href='test.htm#3'>Heading 3</a>
    <a href='test.htm#4'>Heading 4</a>
    <a href='test.htm#5'>Heading 5</a>
    <a href='test.htm#6'>Heading 6</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: chrome most likely is not giving you the right offset top, by right I mean what you are expecting

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Chrome is so fast that your scrollTo() action fires **before** Chrome's default scroll to html anchor event.

Give it a tiny delay by using

```
setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, y);},1)
```

---

Or simply avoid using the **actual element id** as hash name

instead of using

> test.htm#6

use

> test.htm#link_6

then you can get the real id by doing something like

```
window.location.hash.split('_')[1]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll like to add that if it doesn't work, increase interval. Putting 10ms did job for me.

Comment: We also can use `history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'`, that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding the use of JavaScript in favor of creating a dedicated anchor element and then offsetting it above the heading by at least your header height.

This has already been well described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/5951116.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
<div id='navi'>
  <a href='./test2.htm'>Menu</a>
</div>
<div id='main'>
  <div id='spacer'></div>
  <div class='article-wrapper'>
    <a class='anchor' id='1'></a>
    <h3>Heading 1</h3><p class='style1'></p>
  </div>
  <div class='article-wrapper'>
    <a class='anchor' id='2'></a>
    <h3>Heading 2</h3><p class='style1'></p>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

```
#navi {
  height: 50px;
}

#main a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or use CSS variables to remove as much tight coupling as possible:

```
:root {
  --header-height: 50px;
}

#navi {
  height: var(--header-height);
}

#main a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -var(--header-height);
    visibility: hidden;
}
```