# window.scrollTo not working in iOS chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

We are using javascript code to scroll to a div with the given ID. I tried to use

```
jQuery.animate({scrollTop: number})

window.scrollTo(0, number) 

setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, number);}, 1000)
```

I also tried to add `#element_id` to the url to scroll to the element_id.

None of these options are working. Is there any way to get it to work?

**iOS**: 9.2.1

**Chrome**: 48.0.2564.87

http://jsfiddle.net/fXx6c/114/

Answer (score 6):

You can use window.scroll() instead. I tested in your jsfiddle and it worked. Usage would be the same as window.scrollTo().

For example: `window.scroll(0, 485);`

[This answer might explain why window.scrollTo doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694294/3602355)

Comment: this worked for me to fix an issue in Chrome for iOS.  Thanks!