# Scrolling to specific div on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a `div` with a class of "second". I would like to scroll to that element in the page when a `button` is clicked. Below is how I wrote it using jQuery but I'd like to know how to write this in vanilla JavaScript?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Comment: What research have you done so far and have you made any attempt(s) of you own to do this without `jQuery`? If so please include them to your question as this can help give a detailed answered to explain why your attempt didn't function as intended and maybe give a detailed solution. **Edit:** Also an example of the `HTML` would be good since I see this `jQuery` selector is targeting a `class` name of `second` so it would be helpful to know which `class` you want to relate to depending on the `button` clicked.

Comment: For firefox, you can use [scorllTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo). But you will potentially run into issues for Chrome. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691569/javascript-issue-with-scrollto-in-chrome)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getPosition(element) {
        var e = document.getElementById(element);
        var left = 0;
        var top = 0;

        do {
            left += e.offsetLeft;
            top += e.offsetTop;
        } while (e = e.offsetParent);

        return [left, top];
    }

    function jumpTo(id) {
        window.scrollTo(getPosition(id));
    }
```

```html
<a href="#one" onclick="jumpTo('one');">One</a>

<div style="height: 900px"></div>
<div id="one"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tested this on Chrome?

Comment: try again, guy! now I've tested

Comment: Say some thing about your code how it's work. Only code without information is not good way to give ans.

Comment: because is very simple example, the code is easy to read and my english is bad