# How to preload script using integrity and crossorigin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preload

I wish to use preload for my Jquery libs and use the following code.

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js" as="script" integrity="sha256-ZaXnYkHGqIhqTbJ6MB4l9Frs/r7U4jlx7ir8PJYBqbI="
  crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZaXnYkHGqIhqTbJ6MB4l9Frs/r7U4jlx7ir8PJYBqbI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However this always generates the following warnings within chrome.

1. A preload for 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js' is found, but is not used due to an integrity mismatch.
2. The resource https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

The code below will work fine if I use the standard implementation.

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js" as="script">

<script>
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.slim.min.js"
</script>
```

So my question is can I preload external libs and use the crossorigin and integrity (Subresource Integrity) as well?

Thanks

Comment: Add integrity to the preload tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Resources with an integrity attribute can’t reuse preloaded resources (for now) and can also cause double fetches. The `integrity` attribute for link elements has not yet been implemented and there’s an open spec [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677022) about it. This means the presence of any integrity metadata will currently discard preloaded resources. In the wild, it can also result in duplicate requests where you have to make a trade-off between security and performance.

Comment: The below answer should be the accepted one - it has been added to Chromium and it worked for me on Chrome stable 89

Answer (score 9):

Digging this subject up to add some current behaviour that were not mentioned before.

Currently, as of the end of 2020, to `preload` a resource that requires `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes, both attributes **MUST be specified in both tags**, `<link>` and `<script>`, and **MUST be matching**, to be effectively preloaded.

---

### example

```
<link rel="preload" href="http://..." integrity="sha..." crossorigin="anonymous" as="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://..." integrity="sha..." crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

If this not followed, a warning will be issued in the console:

> The resource http://... was preloaded using link preload but not used
> within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure
> it has an appropriate "as" value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: If we don't add integrity and crossorigin on preload, it will be loaded loaded twice too.

Answer (score 8):

This is now supported by several browsers. [Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677022) mentioned in other answer is currently closed. Firefox and Safari also seems to support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to scroll to the page top which has a fixed header. I got the below warning in the console of Chrome.

```
The resource https://xxxxxx.com/xxx.js
was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from
the window’s load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value
and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

And I fixed the problem by adding the setTimeout function. (Give a tiny delay so that your scrollTo() action could fire after Chrome's default scroll to html anchor event.)[JavaScript issue with scrollTo() in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691569/javascript-issue-with-scrollto-in-chrome)

So I changed my source from

```
scrollTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
},
```

to

```
scrollTop() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, 10)
},
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Seems hacky. Surely a scrollTop makes no sense unless the DOM is loaded. So instead of a timeout, can't you just add it to a document.onload or window.onload?