# HTTP/2 server pushed asset downloading twice

Tags: cloudflare, http2, server-push

I am trying to use HTTP/2 server push, powered by Cloudflare. I am trying to push two assets using the following HTTP Header...

```html
Link: </img/whysoslow-hero.jpg>; rel=preload; as=image, </lib/bootstrap.min.css>; rel=preload; as=style
```

The image is reference as a background image in a stylesheet and this is being pushed and then used correctly (downloaded once).

However, I am referencing the stylesheet in the HTML of my page like this...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
```

...and it's being pushed but then also being fetched as well (downloaded twice).

My website is... https://whysoslow.co.uk

Here's a screenshot of the Network tab in Chrome showing that the assets are pushed, but then the stylesheet is downloaded again...

[image: Screenshot of Network tab in Chrome]

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

**EDIT:**

I've since noticed that the console is saying...

> A preload for 'https://whysoslow.co.uk/lib/bootstrap.min.css' is found, but is not used due to an integrity mismatch.

So it's the SRI check that's failing. But I don't understand why, it's fetching the same file, so it should be identical.  Why would they not be identical?

Comment: Why are you using SRI on assets your domain serves own? That's usually used for assets not under your control on another domain (which you then can't push).

Comment: I use Gulp - the assets were originally loaded from CDN but moved them to be locally hosted as I was making performance improvements.  I've removed the SRI now, because like you say, not necessary now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I've figured that out, I've also managed to find the answer...

[How to preload script using integrity and crossorigin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882909/how-to-preload-script-using-integrity-and-crossorigin)

Short answer: You can't preload and use SRI, it's not supported yet.