# Panning Image When Overflow: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what I have is a bigger image wrapped inside a smaller div. So i have scrollbar to see the hidden image parts.
But what I want is the image to pan through mouse drag rather than the scroll bars, basically I want to implement Panning on my image.

I have used Panzoom JS but its other functionalities are ruining my code.
So is there any javascript hack that I can use to Pan image

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainContent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContent">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two examples,
one using a **CSS flexbox centered canvas** in viewport that uses CSS `transform: translate()` (No scrollbars out of the box), and the other using scrollTo() and scrollLeft/Top (Can have browser scrollbars).

## Centered canvas inside viewport area. CSS translate

The formula is quite simple, the transform is relative to the canvas **center**, therefore you simply need to translate it using:

```js
offsetX = currentPointerX - oldPointerX - oldOffsetX
```

Here's a basic example without the constraints calculation:

```js
const Pannable = (elViewport) => {

  const elCanvas = elViewport.firstElementChild;
  const start = {x: 0, y: 0};
  const offset = {x: 0, y: 0}; // The transform offset (from center)
  let isPan = false;

  const panStart = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    isPan = true;
    start.x = ev.clientX - offset.x;
    start.y = ev.clientY - offset.y;
  };

  const panMove = (ev) => {
    if (!isPan) return; // Do nothing
    offset.x = ev.clientX - start.x;
    offset.y = ev.clientY - start.y;
    elCanvas.style.translate = `${offset.x}px ${offset.y}px`;
  };

  const panEnd = () => {
    isPan = false;
  };

  elViewport.addEventListener("pointerdown", panStart);
  addEventListener("pointermove", panMove);
  addEventListener("pointerup", panEnd);
};

document.querySelectorAll(".viewport").forEach(Pannable);
```

```css
.viewport {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  touch-action: none; /* Prevent pointermove default panning */
}

.viewport>* {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```

Or even **simpler, by using [Event.movementX,Y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX)** - because we don't have to remember and store the initial coordinates and manually calculate the difference:

```js
const Pannable = (elViewport) => {

  const elCanvas = elViewport.firstElementChild;
  const offset = {x: 0, y: 0};
  let isPan = false;

  const panStart = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    isPan = true;
  };

  const panMove = (ev) => {
    if (!isPan) return;
    offset.x += ev.movementX;
    offset.y += ev.movementY;
    elCanvas.style.translate = `${offset.x}px ${offset.y}px`;
  };

  const panEnd = () => {
    isPan = false;
  };

  elViewport.addEventListener("pointerdown", panStart);
  addEventListener("pointermove", panMove);
  addEventListener("pointerup", panEnd);
};

document.querySelectorAll(".viewport").forEach(Pannable);
```

```css
.viewport {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  touch-action: none; /* Prevent pointermove default panning */
}

.viewport>* {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```

## Using scrollTo() and scrollLeft/Top

This one is not that good since the inner *canvas* transforms are as browser default: top left corner. (It might be necessary to trigger an automatic scroll in order to center the canvas inside the viewport on init)

The formula:

```js
scrollLeft = oldScrollLeft + oldPointerX - currentpointerX
```

- On pan start ("mousedown") - store the start X,Y positions (account also for the current scrollLeft,scrollTop values)
- On pan ("mousemove") - use `Element.scrollTo(x, y)` where x and y are the initial position minus the current position

```js
const Pannable = (elViewport) => {

  const start = {x: 0, y: 0};
  let isPan = false;

  const panStart = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    isPan = true;
    start.x = elViewport.scrollLeft + ev.clientX;
    start.y = elViewport.scrollTop + ev.clientY;
  };

  const panMove = (ev) => {
    if (!isPan) return;
    elViewport.scrollTo(
      start.x - ev.clientX,
      start.y - ev.clientY
    );
  };

  const panEnd = () => {
    isPan = false;
  };

  elViewport.addEventListener("pointerdown", panStart);
  addEventListener("pointermove", panMove);
  addEventListener("pointerup", panEnd);
};


document.querySelectorAll(".viewport").forEach(Pannable);
```

```css
.viewport {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto; /* Set to hidden to remove scrollbars */
  touch-action: none; /* Prevent pointermove default panning */
}

.viewport > *{
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```

or also, by using Event.movementX,Y

```js
const Pannable = (elViewport) => {

  let isPan = false;

  const panStart = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    isPan = true;
  };

  const panMove = (ev) => {
    if (!isPan) return;
    elViewport.scrollTo(
      elViewport.scrollLeft - ev.movementX,
      elViewport.scrollTop - ev.movementY
    );
  };

  const panEnd = () => {
    isPan = false;
  };

  elViewport.addEventListener("pointerdown", panStart);
  addEventListener("pointermove", panMove);
  addEventListener("pointerup", panEnd);
};


document.querySelectorAll(".viewport").forEach(Pannable);
```

```css
.viewport {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto; /* Set to hidden to remove scrollbars */
  touch-action: none; /* Prevent pointermove default panning */
}

.viewport > *{
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg">
</div>
```

To center-scroll the scrollable element see: [Auto center horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080838/383904)