# ScrollTo / ScrollBy in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scrollto, js-scrollby

Do any of you know why `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` methods in Chrome are not working. In other browsers eg Firefox it works. I can fix the issue by adding a `setTimeout`. An eventListener like load or DOMContentloaded is not working. Thanks and VG.

```
<script>
scrollTo(0,200); // does not work
setTimeout(function a() {scrollTo(0,200);},1); //works.
</script>
```

Comment: This might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694294/3511390 give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mark Ni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841435/mark-ni)'s Comment in [JavaScript issue with scrollTo() in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691569/javascript-issue-with-scrollto-in-chrome) issue:

> Chrome is so fast that your scrollTo() action fires before Chrome's default scroll to html anchor event.