# Offsetting Anchor Links with Fixed Header

Tags: jquery, html, css, header

There've been a few similar posts ([offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header), for example), but those solution doesn't work for my particular case.

I am using jQuery to populate a Table of Contents, specifically the method described here: http://css-tricks.com/automatic-table-of-contents/. It searches for the h2 tags within the article, and then creates anchors links.

The problem is I'm using a fixed header. When I click on one of these anchor links, the target h2 is *underneath* the header. One temporary solution I'm using is:

```
h2:target{
  padding-top:[header-height];
}
```

This works until you scroll back up, and there's a huge gap in the middle of the content. Do y'all have any ideas on how I can offset these anchor links to account for the header? I'd like to keep the HTML as semantic as possible. Any help would be appreciated.

**Here's a jsFiddle of what exactly I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/aweber9/GbNFv/**

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could include `padding-top` and then use negative `margin-top` to balance it out.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/pp9dg/)

```
h2 {
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin-top: -70px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks, man.

Comment: I just found that this can cause display issues in Firefox. I have a lot of <h3> anchors on a page with submit buttons. The minus margins prevent some of the submit buttons from being clicked as they 'overlap' the submit button elements.

Comment: This works like a charm in Chrome and Firefox, but is there an IE-friendly solution?  Doesn't work in IE8, IE9 or IE10 for me.  It's possible this is due to some other code of course but if anyone has insight...

Comment: I've found this works some of the time, but can cause layout issues in other situations. In those situations, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65016689/884640)

Answer (score 19):

Well. I had this issue as well. The best and fastest solution I could find here is to use the following code snippet in your Style tag or CSS file.

```
html
{
  scroll-padding-top: 12vw; /* height of sticky header */
}
```

Answer (score 9):

@Daniel Imms solution is good but if headers had top margin it would be reset by this negative top margin. I found a solution that uses pseudoclasses:

```
h2:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    height: 20px;  /* Give height of your fixed element */
    margin-top: -20px; /* Give negative margin of your fixed element */
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Thus this doesn't reset original top-margin.

Comment: Thank you very much! This should be upvoted, since this does also work on mobile browsers (chrome, safari) whereas padding/margin-only does not work on mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I find both answers together provides the most robust solution across multiple browsers.  I include both in my CSS...

```
a[name]:not([href]) {
    padding-top: 90px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
a[name]:not([href]):before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    padding-top: 90px;
    margin-top: -90px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
:target {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```