# $anchorScroll how to center the element scrolled to?

Tags: angularjs, scrollto

hello I've used this http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html to scroll to elements, but is there a way to set the offset of the anchorScroll? like if I want to center the element in the middle of the view?

Comment: found a dolution to the problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/2207996

Answer (score 0):

Scroll position after scrolling to the anchorScroll offset - (Window height)/2

Answer (score 0):

You can have an offset position, down to the top.

`$anchorScroll.yOffset = 300;`