# Element covered by navbar with higher z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a z-index that is above/higher all other elements on a page, which means it is "ignored". Its height is not counted on the page.

Also, I am using Twitter Bootstrap as my website's foundation.

What happens when I try to redirect to an element with anchor tag. Example:

```
<a href="#idhere">Go to ID</a>
```

Part of the element I redirected to will get covered (covered element = navbar height) by the navbar since its height is not counted on the page.

I'm sure there is a fix to this with JS/jQuery but I would like to know if I can do it through just HTML & CSS.

Thank you. And please do ask for clarification if I did not address my question clear enough.

Comment: See this question : [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use a small trick (I think it still works), just do:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="section-target"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.section-target {
    margin-top: -40px ; // Change to your navbar height
    padding-top: 40px ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs here: [Bootstrap - Navbar fixed top](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

It recommends you adjust the padding of the whole body, to compensate for the height of the nav-bar:

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

You can also use the static top navbar, which does not require the extra padding: [Bootstrap - Navbar static top](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-static-top)