# proper setting for navbar-fixed-top in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I found the menu bar will overwrite some content of first line.  When I click the dropdown 'first', it will locate to the first list item, but it was overwritten by menu bar. I've try apply [one solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FEGtq) Posted in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pewituhujeqe/1/), but failed.

original html is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#first">first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#end">end</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li id="first">first</li>
  <li>a2</li><li>a3</li><li>a4</li><li>a5</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
  <li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li><li>a</li>
  <li id="end">end</li>
</ul>  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SOLUTION [demo](http://jsbin.com/rekaxokucoli/1/edit?html) (as answer)

Comment: What this is called is: anchor links being covered by sticky or fixed position navbar. I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header/20320919#20320919 change to the height of navbar, not the 125 in that code.

Comment: Also, look at the demo on GetBootstrap.com the body has a top padding equal to the height of the fixed navbar. You must use that CSS and the jQuery to not cover up your ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/MOrd1V8CaZ)

Use padding top in the `<li>`

```
 <li id="first" style="padding-top: 50px;">first</li>
```

Comment: Is the body padding-top in document should remove?

Comment: This method will cause extra space before every anchor, for example: http://dlintw.github.io/gobyexample

Answer (score 0):

Protip: Read the docs!

> ### [Body padding required](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add `padding` to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> ```
> body { padding-top: 70px; }
> ```
>
> Make sure to include this **after** the core Bootstrap CSS.