# offset for $location.hash and $anchorScroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have anchor scrolling according to an `id` - as this  -

```
function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
        // set the location.hash to the id of
        // the element you wish to scroll to.
        $location.hash('bottom');

        // call $anchorScroll()
        $anchorScroll();
      };
```

[(taken from angularjs.org)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

I have to set an offset for this `$location.hash('bottom')` due to a fixed header (common problem [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header) )  .

How to get that offset ?

Comment: Alternatively, You can use `$window.scrollTo(x-coord,y-coord )`

Comment: i encountered this problem before, so i have to window.location.hash = 'bottom', and call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

$anchorScroll.yOffset = 20;