# Anchor tags and nav bar not lining up - Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used Bootstrap 3 to create a page with a fixed nav bar top.  In the body I have elements with #anchor tags.  When I click from the nav bar, the element position is displayed but there seems to be a misalignment of the row (approximately the height of the nav bar) - BS3.0 docs say you need to put the padding-top of the body to the height of the nav bar (50px in this case)  and have the body position relative.  There have been posts about the docs not being correct and I can't seem to fix this...

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/richnasser/fkLh9sf4/1/ and the full screen http://jsfiddle.net/richnasser/fkLh9sf4/1/embedded/result/

Click on 'about' and the scrolling should stop at the top of the Santa Claus header.  In my browser (Chrome) it goes well beyond that, hiding the headline.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>North Pole Industries</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="topNavBar">
            <div class="container-fluid"> 
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class ="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
                        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#capabilities">capabilities</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#client">client list</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class = "row" id="home">
                <div><img src= "http://placekitten.com/1200/600" class="img-responsive" alt="kitty"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row">
                <div><img src= "http://placehold.it/1200x400" class="img-responsive" alt="grey"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-md-3" id="about"><h3>Santa Claus <small>chief</h3></small><p class="text-justify">Santa brings over fifteen years of experience in the auto industry through a combination of roles in marketing, field work and wind tunnel studies.  His success is derived from innovative thinking and a keen ability to solve complicated problems.  Santa has worked in both US and International markets doing both strategic and tactical marketing.</p>
                <a href="#santanmore" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#santamore">Read More</a></div>
                <div class="col-md-3" class="headshot"><img src= "http://placehold.it/260x400" class="img-responsive" alt="santa"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3" class="headshot"><img src= "http://placehold.it/260x400" class="img-responsive" alt="rudolf"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><h3>Rudolf <small>dog</h3></small><p class="text-justify">Rudolf counts on over fifteen years experience delivering leadership and marketing capabilities to auto and technology companies, creating profitable and sustainable business growth.  He built his reputation on a solid commitment to customers, passion for marketing excellence, and a strong climate of teamwork.</p>
                <a href="#rudolfmore" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rudolfmore">Read More</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row">
                    <div><img src= "http://placehold.it/1200x400" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

and the css

```
body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: The Bootstrap docs work around the scrolling issue by adding `margin-top: 20px` to elements with `id`s (which is just `h1`, `h2`, etc. in their case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using simple JavaScript. Below Fiddle will help you to figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/aShQL/

In the above fiddle code, update the fromTop height as per your fixed header height.

```
var fromTop = 50; // Give Your fixed header height
```

And also you can find more information at:
[offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: Thanks @Kiran.  I added the code and it worked in Chrome so far.  Will check other browsers etc.  I am surprised that Bootstrap can't handle this and a workaround is needed.  Hate to add more code, but perhaps this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/3424212), with no javascript, only css, and worked for me:

> Give your anchor a class:
>
> ```
> <a class="anchor" id="top"></a>
> ```
>
> You can then position the anchor an offset higher or lower than where
>   it actually appears on the page, by making it a block element and
>   relatively positioning it. -250px will position the anchor up 250px
>
> ```
> a.anchor {
>     display: block;
>     position: relative;
>     top: -250px;
>     visibility: hidden;
> }
> ```

You can adjust the top to the size of you navbar.