# Shift anchor tags in HTML generated from Markdown, by Jekyll

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

A web site I'm working on has a fixed navigation bar at the top. This messes up the positioning of anchor tags. I am aware of the [standard solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header) to this problem, but I'm not sure how I could apply it here.

Markdown source:

```
Go to [closing notes](#closing-notes).

### Closing Notes
```

HTML generated by Jekyll:

```
<p>Go to <a href="#closing-notes">closing notes</a>.</p>

<h3 id="closing-notes">Closing Notes</h3>
```

Any idea greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that Method D outlined in [this post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/#method-D) works fine in my case, since I don't need `border-top` or `margin-top`:

```
h3 {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```