# URL with #anchor over a position:fixed div - is there a non-javascript solution

Tags: javascript, html

this is a problem I'm sure someone else has dealt with.  I have a header which is position-fixed at the top of the page.  then I have a list of elements stacked vertically.  Each element has

```
<a name="post-<?php echo $ID;?>"></a> at its start.
```

So naturally I'd want to have the URL mypage.php?#post-735 scroll that element to the top.  Well, it does exactly what I ask it, imagine that!  Unfortunately of course, since the header is about 150px tall, it is hidden under the header.

My question from there is pretty obvious: 1) any way to use HTML to subtract the 150 or so px from the scroll-down and 2) if this can't be done by HTML, any elegant way to handle it in jQuery or javascript?

Comment: This is a duplicate of so, so many questions, please try searching next time.

Comment: Nit I apologize, I did in fact search and I guess I just wasn't thinking of the right terms to hit an answer.  The suggestions below are also very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an offset like this:

```
<a name="anchor" style="padding-top: 150px; margin-top: -150px;">anchor</a>
```

Or have a look here:
[offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: If you find a duplicate, flag it as such, no need to duplicate the answer here too.