# jquery : how to jump to position without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following function, which scrols to some anchor position, when href is clicked:

```
$("a").click(function() {

href="#myAnchor";
    var fromTop = 95;

    if(href.indexOf("#") == 0) {
      var $target = $(href);
      if($target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - fromTop });
          return false;
        }
      }
 };
  return false;});
```

How to change this function, sothat I jump to my anchor without "scrolling". when the href is clicked, it should be jumbed to myanchor position directly.

Comment: Why don't you just use 'location.href'?

Comment: <a href="#myAnchor">Go to my anchor</a>
<div id="myAnchor">
your html.
</div>
Try it

Answer (score 4):

This is standard feature of HTML called 'bookmarks', no JS required. First place your bookmark where you would like the browser to scroll to:

```
<a name="my-bookmark"></a>
```

Then place your link to it where required:

```
<a href="#my-bookmark">Go to bookmark</a>
```

HTML5 also allows you to specify the bookmark by `id` of the element:

```
<div id="foo">Foo</div>

<!-- in another part of the page, far far away -->
<a href="#foo">Go to foo</a>
```

---

**Update**

If you need to allow padding at the top of the page then you could use the `<a name="x"></a>` method and place them at the required distance above the target, although that could become difficult to maintain.

You could use this JS in that scenario:

```
$("a.bookmark").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr(href);
    var fromTop = $('#fixed-header').height();
    $(window).scrollTop($(href).offset().top - fromTop)
});
```

Comment: I need this function cause of this Issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header

Answer (score 4):

By default, `animate()` has speed set to "400ms". You should put it at 0 :

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top - fromTop }, 0);
```

EDIT: Or use `scrollTop()` as @Rory McCrossan explains

Answer (score 1):

instead of `animate` use `.scrollTop()` this way:

```
$(document).scrollTop($target.offset().top - fromTop);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way without using any script:

assign href the id of the div to where you want to jump to

```
<a href='#jumpto'>Jump</a>

<div id='jumpto'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

without jQuery, **only HTML**

```html
<a href="#aaa">go to aaaaa</a> | <a href="#bbb">go to bbb</a>

<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    
<a name="aaa">aaa</a>
    
    
<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
    
  
<a name="bbb">bbb</a>

<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
```

---

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/0a4Ldgt9/)