# HTML + JS - variation on the floating titlebar and link to named anchor bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a website with a floating title bar. (code below) I have fixed the problem you expect me to be asking about, but I still have another one.

A common problem is when you click on an link to an anchor within the page, the title bar covers up the desired destination, anchor `#part2`. This is a known problem with lots of solutions. (e.g. [This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)) My solution was to simply move the anchor up. That works **but**

- If you paste the http://server/page.html#part2 link into the browser location bar, it works.
- If you click on the link to the anchor within the page, the offset is not honoured. I believe it is because When we click on the `#part2` link, the browser says "Ok, I've got to scroll down to `#part2`. Let me computer where #part2 is. It's at y=1,200 pixels." (made up number). But then when the scroll starts, the floating header div element is floated out to relative positioning and the 1,200 pixel count overshoots.

Please see full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/smorton/7p431smr/

I suspect that my solutions are to find another way to float the title bar, or to find some way to have the page offset recalculated in the `scroll()` function. But I need help with either of these, or an alternate solution.

**Update**

I wasn't explicit, but it is important to me that the floating title bar is *not* at the top of the page when the page is scrolled to the top. Just like in my jsfiddle example. Imagine that this Stack page looked like normal at the top, but when you scrolled down a small bar saying "HTML + JS - variation on the floating titlebar and link to named anchor bug" followed you down. The solutions provided so far, I believe, rely on putting the title bar at the very top, which is not what I'm looking for.

**Solution**

Ok, in the end I just put another div around the header bar of fixed 40px height so that even when the header bar is popped out, that 40px remains reserved.

html:

```
<div id=header_placeholder>
<div id=floatbar class=header> This is the header bar<br>It will follow as you scroll</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#header_placeholder {height: 40px;}
```

---

Floating title bar jquery 1.11 code: (please prefer jsfiddle link)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100)
    {
        $("#floatbar").css({position:'fixed',top:'0'});
        $(".summary").css({margin: '0'});
    }
    else
    {
        $("#floatbar").css({position: 'relative'});
        $(".summary").css({margin: '8 px 0'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/z8s7gugz/1/

A downside to this approach is that the scrollbar can't cover the space of the header as well. In the example it starts 40px off the top.

```
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.header {
  height: 40px;
}
.scrollcontent {
  position: absolute; /* I'm not sure why this is needed, Chrome wont do the overflow without it */
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow: auto;
}

<div class="header"> This is the header bar<br>It will follow as you scroll</div>
<div class="scrollcontent">
  [content]
</div>
```

Doesn't require any JavaScript, [except for perhaps a fallback for the css `calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

I am some what new to HTML, but have you tried using percentages instead of pixels, because when I used pixels Various unexpected things happened

also, check out http://www.codingbyte.com/how-to-create-a-fixed-header-and-footer-layout-in-html/ for your header

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like removing the banner from the flow of the page, messes up the browsers idea of where your named anchor is.

If you remove it from the flow of the page to start with, you wont have this problem.  You can do this by using absolute positioning on your heading when you load the page and adding padding-top to the body content to account for its height.

I've forked your fiddle slightly to show you what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/9c94va97/3/

main changes:

```
body {

  padding-top:40px;

}

.header {

    position:absolute;
    top:0px;

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (Chrome 50) the anchor is still flush with the top of the page. This probably happens because the scrolling element is the document, not the body. I think this approach can work if you move all content inside a `div` (or the body) and put the scroll on that.

Comment: I'm also using Chrome but perhaps I've misunderstood your question.  For me, its getting the calculation right, not overshooting, and the content that shouldn't be covered up is no longer covered up.

Comment: @Halcyon You're right, I think this might be a FF-only, or FF+IE-only issue.