# Jumping to a different part of the same page with a margin

Tags: html, css

I'm using the code below to jump to different sections of [this page](https://www.shiftins.com/insurance/auto/)

```
<span id="section1">
<a href="#section1"></a>
```

Basically when you click the link it jumps to that section but my floating navigation blocks the titles. How do make the page "jump" to "section1" but with a 50 margin?

EDIT: These are acceptable solutions but I forgot to mention that I am using a plug in called "[Table of Contents Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/)" to create these links. I'm not proficient with javascript and need to know what to modify in the plug in code to add these solutions.

Comment: make your navigation block fixed like here https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Answer (score 2):

I used your specific page and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/2145398) to come up with a decent solution. The `<span>` that actually has the anchor id should have the style of `position: relative; top: -100px` and the inner `<strong>` that has the actual text should be `position: relative; top: 100px`. This causes the text to appear where it would normally, but causes the anchor link to send you a bit above the text. You can play with the exact numbers until it looks exactly how you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
section1:target {margin-top: 50px}
```

the `:target` pseudo-class applies properties when you have the id in the URL.