# Navigate to particular section at particular position in html page on click of anchor tag in fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `floating header` which sets on top of the page based on the scroll conditions defined and inside the header i have a navigation wizard and each nav item is wrapped with a anchor tag which point to particular section in the html page. When i click on the anchor tag the window is scrolled to the particular section but content is hidden below the floating bar.

How to make content of particular section display below the header once a `nav item` in the header is clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: I want the UI to be responsive and the constraint is entire page is generated in the code-behind and rendered to a view