# HTML/CSS Anchoring above anchor div

Tags: html, css

I'm using several anchors on a page using the negative margin approach to account for my fixed header (50px). When each section had a specified height, the anchors worked great. When I changed them to work dynamically based on content, they anchor about 5px above where they should, leaving a small sliver of space that's causing issues with my side nav bullets (color changes based on the anchor you're at). Currently, jQuery is generating the code for the anchoring, but I've hard-coded href's to the links without any change. Any thoughts?
Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div id="main-anchor" class="anchor"></div>
<section class="main page-section">
    <div class="section-heading">
```

Anchor class:

```
.anchor {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

[image: the white line in the red shouldn't be showing]

*Edit: Solution - I had two instances of the div height in jQuery, the latter of which was 51 rather than 50 pixels which was creating the gap above my anchor.

Comment: Can you make a simplified sample code on http://jsfiddle.net ? The state of your question currently, does not have enough info or code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of that issue, apologies for the lack of code. Figured out the issue, thanks. I had an issue in my jQuery

Comment: Plz, post it as an answer or commentary to help other people that might run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without javascript

Demo: http://jsbin.com/warixef/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 400px;
}
a {color: white;}
.fixed-header {
  background: slateblue;
  padding: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.page-section {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
}
.section-heading {
  font-size: 110%;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.section-heading:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.anchor {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
.section-content h1 {
  text-align: left;
}
footer {
  text-align: left;
  background: slateblue;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fixed-header">Fixed Header</div>
    <div id="main-anchor" class="anchor"></div>
    <section class="main page-section">
      <a href="#title1" class="section-heading">#Anchor1</a>
      <a href="#title2" class="section-heading">#Anchor2</a>
      <a href="#title3" class="section-heading">#Anchor3</a>
      <div class="section-content">
        <div id="title1" class="anchor"></div>
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <div id="title2" class="anchor"></div>
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <div id="title3" class="anchor"></div>
        <h1>Title 3</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780187/html-css-anchoring-above-anchor-div">SO Answer</a> </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```