# Scroll to section on click (padding needed)

Tags: html, css

Im working on a site that scrolls to a specific section on click but im using a fixed navbar and the title of the section gets lost on click. How can i make the section appear in a specific place? 
Example www.pangeaplustst.com

Comment: Your question is **too broad**, make it specific, provide us some code. What have you done so far?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Would the answer provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13184714/986976 work for you?

Comment: Add padding-top to the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple Solution here.. to avoid the Title going out of focus in your site.

> Remove padding:75px 0; under .page-section.
>
> Remove Section ID and give it to new **Blank DIV** inside it.
>
> Create a new **Blank DIV** inside every section with its **id** and make it `position:absolute, z-index:2, top:-150px, height:150px`

Check the below code

```
<section class="page-section">

<div id="projects" style="
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
"></div>

// Add the above div to every Section

    <div class="container">  
       <div class="section-title text-center">
            <!-- Title -->
            <h2 class="title">Projects</h2>
        </div> .......
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for thank you very much for your help

Comment: upvote and help the community to follow the solution :)