# How to wait for page data to load and render in Angular with Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Is this possible? I want to

1) Get some data on page load with an Observable

2) Update the DOM with that data and render the HTML

3) Find the pixel location of something

4) Scroll the page by an amount dependent on that location

I don't know how to make (3) wait until (2) has finished.

I'm working on [this project](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/master/src/app/debate/debate.page.ts#L41-L49) that uses ngrx and Angular 2 and RxJS Observables to replace [this one](http://www.bernierebuttals.org) that uses JQuery.

Here's the particular problem I'm trying to solve. If you pass an anchor id in a url like mypage.html#34, a page will scroll to that point. That's how pages have worked forever. The problem is that if there are fixed headings as divs with css `position:fixed` at the top of the page, the target anchor in the document will be moved to the top of the page, behind the headings. Moreover, it won't scroll if the data and anchors aren't there initially. So as far as I can tell you need to go to lengths in javascript in order to make it work right. If you know another way, without using an IFRAME, please let me know. I'm open to ideas. I want the anchor id to be in the page's url so I can share links to this page that contains a list and expands the details for the given item and scrolls to it.

Comment: Why not set your content container with a padding-top same as hearder's height? html: `<header></header><content></content>`,  css: `header {position: fixed, height: 20px}; content {padding-top: 20px}`.

Comment: Is <content> an html element? I could only find this, which is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

Comment: My last comment is no good. For "offsetting content against fixed header", you may refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header. There are some solution based on pure css. And I have mad a codepen with one of the solution, http://codepen.io/rxjs-space/pen/OWLeBd

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a nice solution. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in my case, probably because the page is rendered on the client so the anchor isn't ready when the browser tries to scroll to it. Also the header is fixed initially, then scrolls off the top after some random amount of content scrolling. It disappears and reappears. I don't understand that yet. I pushed my changes. Here's how it looks: http://imgur.com/a/AUeJO I'll see if any of the others do the trick

Comment: The odd behavior of the fixed header (disappears and reappears) may be caused by the `<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>` in your `layout.component.ts`. I don't know about material design. Maybe you can get some help for their gitter channel: https://gitter.im/angular/material2?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge

Comment: Why don't you create a subject out of the pixel location and then create an observer of the scroll down function. Whenever the pixel value changes, the function shall run?

Answer (score 0):

1. create one service:

   `@injectable 
   export class whateverService(){
       //getter & setter service for position
   }`
2. in your component class

   `export whateverComponent implements OnInit(){
       constructor(private serviceObj:whateverService){} 
       ngOnInit(){
           // write your logic here like : 
           let x = this.serviceObj.getFunction();
           setTimeout(function() {
               document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView();
           }, 100);
       } 
   }`

Comment: I think that won't work if it takes more than 100 ms to get the data.

Comment: yes for that need to put default id or it will take previous one