# How to apply an offset to a #link on another page

Tags: html, css, anchor, offset

I got a website which basically is 80% index.html plus a few minor subpages.
Index.html is divided into few sections.
However, the navigation has position:fixed and height of - say - 100px, so links like

```
<a href="#section">
```

need a 100px offset.
I achieve it through jQuery (ill leave all ifs for specific sections out):

```
$("#navigation a").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var offset = $("#section1").offset().top - 100;
    $(window).scrollTop(offset);
}
```

The problem is that when i navigate to index.html from subpages, this trick won't work, so i must not use this function on subpages and simply "allow default".

Is there a way to navigate to a #section of an other html document with a proper offset (cant be hard coded)?

Comment: Found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header. The solution below worked for blocks of content, but for individual `<sup>` footnotes within text content, it would add a newline before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without Javascript.

Assumed on the index.html all targets having the class section. With this CSS snippet the fixed navigation does not hide any target.

```css
body {
   padding-top: 60px;
   margin-top: 0px;
}

 #fixed-nav { 
   position:fixed;
   height:50px;
   line-height:50px;
   vertical-align:middle;    
   background:#000;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   color:#FFF;
   padding-left:5px;
}

#fixed-nav a {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sections .section {
  height:400px;
  padding-left:5px;
}

#sections .section:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -60px; 
  height: 60px; 
  visibility: hidden;
```

```html
<div id="fixed-nav">
   <a href="#target-1">To target 1</a>
   <a href="#target-2">To target 2</a>
   <a href="#target-3">To target 3</a>
   <a href="#target-4">To target 4</a>
   <a href="#target-5">To target 5</a>
</div>

<div id="sections">
  <div class="section" id="target-1">
    Target 1
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="target-2">
    Target 2
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="target-3">
    Target 3
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="target-4">
    Target 4
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="target-5">
    Target 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this not work with `position:sticky`?