# Combining anchor-offset and target-styling on a html-table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to combine an anchor-offset with an anchor-target-style on a table-row.

Having the anchor-ID applied to the table row and styling it via 'tr:target td' does achieve the desired look, while the solutions provided here ( [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header) ) achieve the desired offset, but only for text.

I can't use the top-voted solution as it requires the "display: block"-attribute which is incompatible to the tr-tag as far as I know. If somehow possible I would prefer a only css/html solution

The structure I use:

```
<table>
<tr id="anchor-target1"> <td> Something </td> </tr>
<tr id="anchor-target2"> <td> Something </td> </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:** JSFiddle-Example. Goal is to combine both functions: https://jsfiddle.net/7rknaqwu/5/

Comment: Could you perhaps do the adjustment to the table instead of the rows?

Comment: This way I can only target the whole table and not the single rows, as the way shown in the thread I linked simply moves the whole target to achieve an anchor-offset

Comment: I'd need to see a more complete example to see the problem.

Comment: Example for tr-Highlighting:
`<a href="#AnchorTarget1">Anchor Target 1</a><br>
<a href="#AnchorTarget2">Anchor Target 2</a><br><br>

<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="AnchorTarget1">
         <td>Content1A</td>
         <td>Content1B</td>
      </tr>
   <tr id="AnchorTarget2">
         <td>Content2A</td>
         <td>Content2B</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: Example for offset using span-elements:
`<a href="#Target1">Anchor Target 1</a><br>
<a href="#Target2">Anchor Target 2</a><br>

<table style="display:block">
   <tbody>
      <a class="anchor" id="Target1"></a><tr>
         <td>Content1A</td>
         <td>Content1B</td>
      </tr><br>
   <a class="anchor" id="Target2"></a><tr>
         <td>Content2A</td>
         <td>Content2B</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
CSS: tr:target td{
background-color: red;}

a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    visibility: hidden;}`

Comment: You should provide an example of the actual problem in your original question. I don't believe the comments you've added reproduce your issue entirely.