# how to make anchor tags scroll without being covered by position: fixed area

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a header at the top with position:fixed, so that it stays at the top of the screen as the user scrolls. That works fine.

In the body underneath there are anchor tags. And when you click on a link that takes you to one of these anchors, the browser displays the page with that that anchor at the very top. Even though this is under the header.

Here's a simplified page that demonstrates the problem:

```html
<html>
<style>
  .header {
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
  
  .body {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
</style>
<div class="header">
  This is the header.
</div>
<div class="body">
  <p><a href="#10">Line 10</a> <a href="#20">Line 20</a></p>
  This is the body.<br/> Line 2<br/> Line 3<br/> Line 4<br/> Line 5<br/> Line 6<br/> Line 7<br/> Line 8<br/> Line 9<br/>
  <a name="10" /> Line 10<br/> Line 11<br/> Line 12<br/> Line 13<br/> Line 14<br/> Line 15<br/> Line 16<br/> Line 17<br/> Line 18<br/> Line 19<br/>
  <a name="20" /> Line 20<br/> Line 21<br/> Line 22<br/> Line 23<br/> Line 24<br/> Line 25<br/> Line 26<br/> Line 27<br/> Line 28<br/> Line 29<br/> Line 30<br/> Line 31<br/> Line 32<br/> Line 33<br/> Line 34<br/> Line 35<br/> Line 36<br/> Line 37<br/>  Line 38<br/> Line 39<br/> Line 40<br/>
</div>

</html>
```

Click on the "Line 10" link and it displays with the header, and right below the header, the first thing visible is ... line 11.

I'd like it to work so that if you click on a link for line 10, that line 10 will be visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to the dialog box at the top referring me to another similar, maybe essentially the same, question. @johannchopin's answer on this question worked for me so I accepted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a response to this type of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842865/8583669). It use the trick of `padding-top: size; margin-top: -size;`:

```css
.body a {
  /* Adjust here the size */
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>
  .header {
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
  
  .body {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
</style>
<div class="header">
  This is the header.
</div>
<div class="body">
  <p><a href="#10">Line 10</a> <a href="#20">Line 20</a></p>
  This is the body.<br/> Line 2<br/> Line 3<br/> Line 4<br/> Line 5<br/> Line 6<br/> Line 7<br/> Line 8<br/> Line 9<br/>
  <a name="10" /> Line 10<br/> Line 11<br/> Line 12<br/> Line 13<br/> Line 14<br/> Line 15<br/> Line 16<br/> Line 17<br/> Line 18<br/> Line 19<br/>
  <a name="20" /> Line 20<br/> Line 21<br/> Line 22<br/> Line 23<br/> Line 24<br/> Line 25<br/> Line 26<br/> Line 27<br/> Line 28<br/> Line 29<br/> Line 30<br/> Line 31<br/> Line 32<br/> Line 33<br/> Line 34<br/> Line 35<br/> Line 36<br/> Line 37<br/>  Line 38<br/> Line 39<br/> Line 40<br/>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked great with my simplified mock up page ... but it didn't work with my real page. On my real page, the content is a bunch of clickable entries -- click one and it produces a pop up. But this technique makes the entries overlap, so when you position the mouse on one and click, the browser thinks you're actually on one a couple of lines down. Perhaps this could be fixed by putting a z-order on every entry.

Comment: Oh wait, it does work. I just can't make the target of the links be clickable. I have to create a separate tag to be the link target.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

This happens because when clicking an anchor the browser will jump to that anchor and align it at the top of the user window. It ignores the fixed element, because a fixed element is no longer inside the document flow.

In this case you could use a simple CSS 'trick', but that depends on if the header will stay the same. If it changes I would recommend using JavaScript OR use media queries to adjust the header correction when needed.

**CSS Only**

I've made an example in JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5t3hj9a0/2/)

HTML code:

```
<div class="header">
  This is the header.
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    <a href="#anchor_a">Anchor A</a> 
    <a href="#anchor_b">Anchor B</a>
  </p>

  <div class="example-box">
   <h3 class="example-box_header">
     <span id="anchor_a" class="example-box_id"></span>
     Header 1
   </h3>
   <p>Some long list here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="example-box">
   <h3 class="example-box_header">
      <span id="anchor_b" class="example-box_id"></span>
      Header 2
   </h3>
   <p>Some long list here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.header {
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Just example code: */
.example-box {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 1vw 0;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

.example-box_header {
  position: relative; /* This is needed, otherwise the anchor would not be relative to the header */
}


.example-box_id {
  width: 1px; /* 1 */
  height: 1px; /* 1 */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible; /* 1 */
  top: -20px; /* Header height compensation */
}

/* [1] To make sure to visually hide the anchor */
```

What it actually does is adding a extra span inside the box/header where it needs to jump to. That extra span is used as the anchor and negatively placed (top) with the height of the header.