# fixed navbar overlaps anchor tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, navbar, anchor

I am using React and try to create a single-page-website with a fixed navbar. The navbar has items as "home", "project", "team", "contact" in it. I am using anchor tags to link these items in the navbar to the individual sections. So, when I click e.g. "project", it jumps to this section, but the top of the section is covered by the navbar (see screenshot below).

So my question is: is it possible to use the anchor tags in a way that the top of a section is not covered by the navbar?

Screenshot: [This is how it looks when you click "projekt" in the navbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mPz0.png)

My problem is similar to this issue: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header". Unfortunately, I am not sure how to adapt the proposed solutions to my problem. (i'm new to coding, maybe thats the reason :D)

Here is my code:

This is my navbar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { IoIosChatbubbles } from "react-icons/io";

class Navbar extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <nav className="navbar">
                        <div className="container-navbar" >
                            <div className="navbar__bubble">
                                <a href="#home">
                                <IoIosChatbubbles size="2.3em"></IoIosChatbubbles>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="navbar__title">
                                <h2> <a href="#home">Filterbub</a></h2>
                            </div>
                            <div className="navbar__navigation-items">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#projekt">Projekt</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </nav>  
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

This is, as an example, the project section:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 

class Projekt extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <main id="projekt" style={{marginTop: '100px'}}>
                <div className="container-pagecontent">
                <h1>Unser Projekt</h1>
                <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet shoulder short ribs shankle brisket. Biltong ham hock shankle pork chop pork flank. Tri-tip chicken hamburger, swine doner bresaola filet mignon picanha sirloin shoulder. Cow doner chuck ribeye, t-bone tri-tip ham hock shoulder pork. Tail capicola sirloin short loin jerky turducken ground round tri-tip shankle sausage bresaola salami bacon. Landjaeger sausage ham jowl filet mignon chicken ground round porchetta burgdoggen short loin. Ham hock short ribs pork chop filet mignon, andouille cupim pork belly alcatra buffalo turducken shoulder.</p>
                <p>Prosciutto t-bone cow flank andouille ham. Short loin jerky pork loin, rump tail pastrami porchetta shankle shank turducken cupim spare ribs. Cupim bresaola pancetta tail ham prosciutto shoulder short ribs buffalo t-bone sausage filet mignon swine chicken. Spare ribs ground round hamburger short loin chicken jerky pork chop boudin landjaeger drumstick doner pork belly.</p>
                </div>
            </main>
            )
    }
}

export default Projekt
```

This is the code of the scss for the navbar.

```
.navbar {
    background: #1763A5;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: .7rem 0;
    height: 47px;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lighten(black, 30%);
}

.navbar__bubble {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.navbar__bubble a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.navbar__bubble a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__title {
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: $m-size;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__title h2 a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.navbar__title h2 a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__navigation-items {
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: $m-size;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar__navigation-items ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 30px; 
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar__navigation-items a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.navbar__navigation-items a:hover,
.navbar__navigation-items a:active {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar__navigation-items a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar__subtitle {
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

Let me know if you need more insights into my code.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the position for `.navbar` from `position: fixed;` to `position: sticky;`

Comment: It looks like you didn't include all your styling in the question can you please create a codesandbox so I can check it out?