# CSS only smooth scrool with offset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using the classic anchor tag approach to click and scroll to a specific div

```
<a href="#scrollTo"></a>
<div id="scrollTo"></div>
```

The problem that im facing is that this approach scrolls till the div top margin in on the top of the screen. Is there a way of scrolling it only galf the way with css only, or I will have to use javscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another element inside the `div`.
If you place a `positioned` element inside the `scrollto div` with a negative margin. The negative margin will be the offset you want. Make the inner element have a height of `0px`, that way it won't be visible to your users.

You will need to put the `id` on that element of course.

```
<div id="olddiv">
    <div id="scrollTo" style="margin-top: -100px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this doesnt work because I still need the content inside scrollTo to be visible, and it only become visible when the anchor tag is clicked

Comment: @BrunoPigatto put the content inside "olddiv" beneath "scrollTo" not inside the "scrollTo".

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using an offset on the div you are using for the anchor:
[offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)