# How do I make a link jump to the correct part of another page?

Tags: html, anchor

I've made a link to jump to a part of another page using the following HTML:

```
<a href="./about-us.html#our-mission"> Read more &#187;</a>
```

This is the id of the link where it goes to:

```
<div id="our-mission" name="our-mission">
```

The problem is that it is dropping me a few lines down from the heading "Our Mission" on the targeted page.

How do I get it to target the correct spot, please? Tnx.

Comment: You need to provide a runnable example for your question. With this little info, we're not sure what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set an offset.
You sould try something like this:

https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

[offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

This could be a solution for your problem but i need a code example for an concrete solution. the ::before pseudo class is the key.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
nav {
  background: yellow;
  height: 80px;
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.spacer{
  height: 80px;
}
.content{
  height: 1000px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#green {
  background: green;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
h1 {
  margin:0;
}
h1::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -80px; 
  height: 80px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#green">Green</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#red">Red</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  
</nav>

<div class="spacer">
</div>
<div class="content" id="green">
<h1>Green</h1>
</div>
<div class="content" id="red">
<h1>RED</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer but I've tried executing it without success. I don't have enough experience to make great changes. I'd just completed a two-week web design bootcamp before trying to create a simple website for myself. It's very exciting and challenging in equal parts. I am having to redo my website because my initial template was not very mobile friendly. At this point I don't have a lot of time or motivation to experiment or take  any steep learning curves, but I can let you take a look at my full html and css, if I there is a legit way to share it privately?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31283924)

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Since i dont have an code-examlple i cant serve the best/right answer. It depence on the source of the problem.

Comment: @ladyem sorry but i can't offer you free support for your page. I added an example how to solve the problem. :)

Comment: No, problem. I'll keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
    #our-mission {padding-top:3%;}
```

Adjust percentage as needed.

Comment: This would mess up his styling...