# Anchor Link to Jump to a Specific Part of a next Page

Tags: html, jquery, css

in home page i have services listed with readmore button, when user click on readmroe button i wan to send to respective services page section with have specific id.

but due to sticky navbar with height of 50px on scroll in overlapping the content in services page

home page:

```
<header>
    <nav id="navbar" class="sticky">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <div class="top-top">
    <ul class="temp-op">
      <li><a href="services.html#ser-1" >Service-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html#ser-2" >Service-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html#ser-3" >Service-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html#ser-4" >Service-4</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html#ser-5" >Service-5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[image]

so when user click on services-1, services-2 and so on it should redirect to services page id section
services page:

```
<header>
<nav id="navbar" class="sticky">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


</header>
  
  <section id="ser-1" class="service">
    <h2>Service-1</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-1 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-2" class="service">
    <h2>Service-2</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-2 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-3" class="service">
    <h2>Service-3</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-3 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-4" class="service">
    <h2>Service-4</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-4 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-5" class="service">
    <h2>Service-5</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-5 goes here.</p>
  </section>
```

[image: services-page]

as we can see that when we click readmore button of home page thats redirect to services pages id section due to sticky header content of services page is hiding, how can we fixing this redirection issues overlapping content

i have tried css offset but didnt work

```
.destination {


scroll-margin: 100px 0 0 0;
 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Answer (score 1):

**The Default CSS option is used section top padding or  second option is used offset Top using jQuery**

```css
section{
    height:100vh;
    background:red;
    padding:15px;
    padding-top:60px;
}
section:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #eee;
}
a {
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
nav{
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 13px;
}
nav li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 5px ;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav id="navbar" class="sticky">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#ser-1">Service 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ser-2">Service 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ser-3">Service 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ser-4">Service 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


</header>
  
  <section id="ser-1" class="service">
    <h2>Service-1</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-1 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-2" class="service">
    <h2>Service-2</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-2 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-3" class="service">
    <h2>Service-3</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-3 goes here.</p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="ser-4" class="service">
    <h2>Service-4</h2>
    <p>Description of Service-4 goes here.</p>
  </section>
```